# entity framework model first

Tags: entity-framework-5

We are weighing the pros and cons between Model First and DB first development. I found the following
Model First
Pros
1. C# dev need not understand SQL stmts.
2. C# dev can create a more specific entity for his business req.
Cons
1. Cannot use finer features available in vendor DB (i.e. Constraints for column in SQL server)

For DB first the pros and cons reverses. Is there anything big am missing here. I am slowly tilting towards DB first pls. advice.

Comment: What about code first?

Answer (score 0):

According to your project, currently you can use three available approaches: DB First, Model First and Code First.

Obviously there are trade-offs which should be considered before using each of them.

While developing business objects and their relationship, you have already produced much of your data model and prohibiting this redundancy is the idea behind new approaches and technologies. With this simple point in mind, if data model is going to change frequently, DB First is not a good choice.

Although the whole idea is brilliant, new approaches are not mature enough yet (witness `Entity Framework` frequent releases and major changes). They cannot completely eliminate mentioned redundancy and they cannot cover all of DB First capabilities in their frameworks. Also, the work is done through middle layers which diminishes performance compared to DB First approach. Unfortunately you will not notified about uncovered capabilities unless you are in the middle of your project. So, if you need sophisticated capabilities or have a complex data model and the business model is not subject to frequent changes, and/or performance is a high priority, DB First is your choice.

What is happening at this struggle, to my opinion is clarifying the right question which should be answered. As database technologies priority is stability, they are not subject to frequent or major changes (witness relational databases). From development point of view, we have our objects and their relations defined and storing them in collections and easily retrieving them when needed so why should bother where and how this volatile objects (they are in RAM at run-time) are going to be stored. While mentioned technologies are endeavors from developers side, there are endeavors from database technology side i.g. In Memory Databases, Object Oriented databases...